# Can someone please convert this to a normal for loop format in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to display tweets and the following code works but now I have to run a method on the text of the tweet and want the following code in a normal for loop format and return the dictionary later.

```
def get_tweets(username):
    tweets = tweepy_api.user_timeline(screen_name=username)               
    return [{'tweet': t.text,
              'created_at': t.created_at, 
              'username': username,
              'headshot_url': t.user.profile_image_url}
           for t in tweets]
```

Comment: What you see is called *list comprehension*, you might want to google that

Comment: `for t in tweets: l.append({ ... })`…!?

Comment: @krishna's answer is correct, but consider learning how list comprehension works in Python. This isn't complicated. For example, this seems to a be good short explanation, with examples - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Answer (score 2):

check this.

```
def get_tweets(username):
    tweets = tweepy_api.user_timeline(screen_name=username)
    result_list = []
    for t in tweets:
        result_list.append(
            {'tweet': t.text,
             'created_at': t.created_at,
             'username': username,
             'headshot_url': t.user.profile_image_url
             }
        )

    return result_list
```